# PictureBox transparent in all tools in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, picturebox

How could I make the PictureBox transparent.

My work :

[image: My work]

I already set the PictureBox BackColour to transparent but still I cannot see the DataGridView also the TextBox beside status label.

Can some one help me to achieve like this.

I want to acheive :

[image: I want to acheive]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what's the extension of your image you want to put in your picturebox field?

Comment: the extension of my image is png

Comment: if you open your image with gimp, can you see if the background is transparent?

Comment: gimp? i created my image in adobe photoshop and save it as png file

Comment: alright, if you open your image with photoshop, is the background transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting background color to `Transparent` can lead to misunderstandings. The white colour that you see is the form background.

There is no way to make a control transparent without drawing the picture by yourself in the form's `Paint` event

**EDIT:**

Say you have a `DataGridView1` control you want to draw the image on:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint

        ' Create image.
        Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("pic.png")

        ' Adjust this as you need
        Dim x As Single = 100
        Dim y As Single = 50
        Dim width As Single = 100
        Dim height As Single = 100

        ' Draw image on top of the control
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height)

    End Sub
```

Comment: I edited the code. Use your top control `Pain` event

Comment: in panel. there is some item dock to fill with it. 1st. tabcontrol. then inside of it filled with datagridview then i want to put your code in panel paint event but the image is at the back of tabcontrol

Comment: Take a look here http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?531022-Draw-Common-quot-Picture-quot-on-All-Controls